# Python3 - JSON error

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am currently visitting the API of OldSchool RuneScape which returns strings in JSON, but won't work for me.

My current code:

```
import json
import urllib.request

name = input('OSRS name? ')
url = 'http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player={0}'.format(name) 

open_url = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
read_url = open_url.read().decode()
format_to_string = str(read_url)

j = json.loads(format_to_string)
print(j)
```

but if I try for example as name itz_craft, I get an error.

```
OSRS name? itz_craft
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Programming/Python3/RuneScape/json_test.py", line 11, in <module>
j = json.loads(format_to_string)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 346, in decode
raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 7 - line 28 column 1 (char 6 - 315)
```

I hope that somebody can help me out with this problem so I can avoid problems later with JSON, because I am going to use this so much.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Are you sure the API is returning JSON? I went to the URL in my browser and the page is text / html. Is there a `format` parameter you can specify `JSON` with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Runescape HiScores [API documentation](http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Hiscores_APIs) says that the returned value is:

> a newline delimited string of CSVs

So you can't parse it as JSON, because it isn't.

Comment: How would I do this with a CSV?

Comment: Python has a CSV parser in the standard library, check out the CSV module in the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) or in [this tutorial](https://pymotw.com/2/csv/). If you have another question regarding the CSV module you should make a separate question.

Comment: If I have helped you or pointed you in the right direction, please consider marking this as the accepted answer.